# How to pass a word macro a String parameter

Tags: java, vba, ms-word

I would like to call a word macro from a java program and pass the macro a search string. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Com4J to generate the access classes for Word. Now call your macro as you would from VBA.